# Specific conversion of EBNF into BNF

Tags: bnf, ebnf

```
<A> ::= <B> x {<B> <D>} y <B>
<B> ::= <C> (w|z) <C> <D>
<C> := m [n] <D> <E> 
<D> := q | null
<E> := p | null
```

How would you convert this EBNF into BNF?

Answer (score 1):

Different people use a different syntax for EBNF, and I'm not sure which one you are using. Your grammar in EBNF (**ISO/IEC 14977: 1996(E)**) would look like this:

```
A = B, "x", {B, D}, "y", B;
B = C, ("w" | "z"), C, D;
C = "m", ["n"], D, E; 
D = ["q"];
E = ["p"];
```

Assuming you use `null` for the empty string. Notice that this could be further simplified.

Some productions must be added to convert this to BNF:

- `{ expr }` can be replaced by inserting a production `P := empty |
  expr P` where `empty` represents the empty string.
- `[ expr ]` can be replaced by inserting  `P := empty | expr`.
- Any expression `( expr )` can be replaced by adding a new production
  `P := expr`.

So something like this:

```
A -> B x F y B
F -> empty | B D F
B -> C G C D
G -> w | z
C -> m H D E
H -> empty | n
D -> q | empty
E -> p | empty
```

Again, assuming that with `null` you mean the empty string.